# Game of life is running slow

Tags: nim-lang

I am trying to simulate n-dimensional game of life for first t=6 time steps. My Nim code is a straightforward port from Python and it works correctly but instead of the expected speedup, for n=4, t=6 it takes 2 seconds to run, which is order of magnitude slower than my CPython version. Why is my code so slow? What can I do to speed it up? I am compiling with `-d:release` and `--opt:speed`

I represent each point in space with a single 64bit integer.
That is, I map `(x_0, x_1, ..., x_{n-1})` to sum `x_i * 32^i`. I can do that since I know that after 6 time steps each coordinate `-15<=x_i<=15` so I have no overflow.

The rules are:

```
alive - has 2 or 3 alive neigbours: stays alive
      - different number of them: becomes alive
dead - has 3 alive neighbours: becomes alive
     - else: stays dead
```

Below is my code. The critical part is the proc `nxt` which gets set of active cells and outputs set of active cells next time step. This proc is called 6 times. The only thing I'm interested in is the number of alive cells.

I run the code on the following input:

```
.##...#.
.#.###..
..##.#.#
##...#.#
#..#...#
#..###..
.##.####
..#####.
```

Code:

```
import sets, tables, intsets,  times, os, math

const DIM = 4
const ROUNDS = 6
const REG_SIZE = 5
const MAX_VAL = 2^(REG_SIZE-1)

var grid = initIntSet()

# Inits neighbours
var neigbours: seq[int]
proc initNeigbours(base,depth: int) =
    if depth == 0: 
        if base != 0:
            neigbours.add(base)
    else:
        initNeigbours(base*2*MAX_VAL-1, depth-1)
        initNeigbours(base*2*MAX_VAL+0, depth-1)
        initNeigbours(base*2*MAX_VAL+1, depth-1)
initNeigbours(0,DIM)
echo neigbours

# Calculates next iteration:
proc nxt(grid: IntSet): IntSet =
    var counting: CountTable[int]
    for x in grid:
        for dx in neigbours:
            counting.inc(x+dx)
    for x, count in counting.pairs:
        if count == 3 or (count == 2 and x in grid):
            result.incl(x)

# Loads input
var row = 0
while true:
    var line = stdin.readLine
    if line == "":
        break
    for col in 0..<line.len:
        if line[col] == '#':
            grid.incl((row-MAX_VAL)*2*MAX_VAL + col-MAX_VAL)
    inc row

# Run computation
let time = cpuTime()
for i in 1..ROUNDS:
    grid = nxt(grid) 

echo "Time taken: ", cpuTime() - time
echo "Result: ", grid.len
discard stdin.readLine
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code runs in my computer in about 0.02:

```
Time taken: 0.020875947
Result: 2276

Time taken: 0.01853268
Result: 2276

Time taken: 0.021355269
Result: 2276
```

I changed the part where the input is read to this:

```
# Loads input
var row = 0
let input = open("input.txt")
for line in input.lines:
  for i, col in line:
    if col == '#':
      grid.incl((row-MAX_VAL)*2*MAX_VAL + i-MAX_VAL)
  inc row
input.close()
```

But it shouldn't impact the performance, it just looks better to my eyes. I compiled with:

```
nim c -d:danger script.nim
```

Using Nim 1.4.2. `-d:danger` is the flag for maximum speed before entering deeper waters.

But even compiling in debug mode:

```
$ nim c -r script.nim

Time taken: 0.07699487199999999
Result: 2276
```

Way faster than 2 seconds. There has to be other problem in your end. Sorry for the non-answer.

Comment: This is an excelent answer! :) Good to know problem is not with the code. I don't know what the problem was, but after updating Nim to 1.4.2 it now runs in 0.02 secs on my machine too.